# git hook bash does not work

Tags: git, bash

working hard on configuration of my git repository, but stil no success.

Goal: as soon i make a push on my lokal repo, to the dev branch, it will merged with master brench.

post-update (hook)

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> #
> # An example hook script to prepare a packed repository for use over
> # dumb transports.
> #
> # To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-update".
>
> LOGFILE=/www/htdocs/w00dac5d/_production/.git_push_log.tmp
>
> &> $LOGFILE
>
> echo 'push-start'
>
> echo `basename $PWD`
> #cd ../
> #echo `basename $PWD`
>
> git status
> git checkout master
>
> echo 'push-checkout'
> git merge dev
>
> exec git-update-server-info
> ```

getting errors like

"its not a git repo" but i check teh folder an it is the right one.

[image]

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432026/gitosis-admin-git-push-failed-exec-hooks-post-update (with its comment), and see if you need to set `GIT_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: it is not really clear where to set it

Comment: I believe in your hook script, just to make sure Git knows where to look when you are making your git commands like `git status`: the current directory isn't the only thing that matter.

Comment: after cd ../
echo `basename $PWD` he is in _production, this is the git repo...

Comment: I would still recommend you try to set `GIT_DIR` to that `.git` directory full path (and `GIT_WORK_TREE` to the parent directory), to be extra sure. Test it and see of the errors persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that in a `post-update` hook in a non-bare repository, `GIT_DIR` is set to `.` and your current directory is the `.git` directory.  For such details for each different git hook, see [this underrated blog post](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/)  ;)

That means that if you do `cd ..` then `GIT_DIR` will still be `.` but your current directory will no longer be the `.git` directory.  Try beginning your hook script with:

```
export GIT_DIR=/whereever/production/.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/whereever/production/
```

... to be safe - the rules about how `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` interact are fiddly.